# How can I get DASK on my virtual private cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, machine-learning, dask

We are looking for a parallel computing solution at my company and we settled on DASK.  I have to get it into a virtual private cloud but its open source, and I have no experience doing that.  Can anyone advise on how to set it up on a VPC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with the simplest deployment - which is to get a big box on Amazon or Azure, install the Anaconda python distribution, and launch dask (and jupyter).  If you've got a data scientist using Jupyter on that box, they can just execute

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
```

Which will spin up a `LocalCluster` on that machine.

If you want to access the dask cluster from a different machine instead, you just need to execute a few processes

To start the scheduler:

```
$ dask-scheduler
Scheduler started at 127.0.0.1:8786
```

And then start a few workers (ideally, one per core)

```
$ dask-worker 127.0.0.1:8786
$ dask-worker 127.0.0.1:8786
$ dask-worker 127.0.0.1:8786
```

You can then expose 8786 to the outside world via ssh tunnels

There are many more complex setups - running on k8s, or on the elastic container service, but whether you need that, really depends on your use case.

Saturn Cloud has an [enterprise Dask product](https://www.saturncloud.io) on the AWS marketplace that will do a more sophisticated k8s deployment for you. (disclaimer: I'm one of the founders)